# Dataflow Job fails with "Unable to bring up enough workers"

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

My Dataflow job is failing with the following message, how should I debug?

> Workflow failed. Causes: (65a939e801f185b6): Unable to bring up enough
>   workers: minimum 1, actual 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service will output this message when it is unable to allocate a virtual machine from [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) to execute the job.  Please check your quota in the [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/quotas).

Comment: One of my dataflow jobs failed with this message. The job id is 2016-11-16_13_53_51-16676218324204974458 .
You ask to check quota in the answer. So what do i check in quota?
Is there any threshold of some parameter, we need to keep track of to avoid seeing this message?

Comment: You need to check the Compute Engine quota (cores, etc.) for your project.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the same thing. However, switching zone solved the problem for me. I believe it gives the same error message sometimes when there are no free resources.